# Parsing JSON content in AJAX response

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, jsp

I am trying to parse JSON content in a AJAX response inside JSP. The response is a list of objects.I am not able read individual variables.Please find the attached code for your reference.

JsonTest.jsp

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
COMPONENT CODE : <input name="PartCode" id="PartNo" type="text" />
<br><br>
COMPONENT DESCRIPTION : <input name="desc" id ="Description" value=''>
<br><br>
QUANTITY : <input name="qty" id="Quantity" type="text" value=""/>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#PartNo').keypress(function(event){
var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
if(keycode == '13'){
    varPartCode = $('#PartNo').val();
     $.ajax({  
            type: "Post",  
            url: "submit",
            data: "PartCode="+varPartCode,
            headers: {Accept : "application/json;charset=utf-8","Content-Type":"application/json;charset=utf-8"},
            success: function(json){ 
                var rep = JSON.parse(json);
                alert(rep.name);
             }                
          });
}   
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

TestBean.java

```
package test.json.MyJsonCode;

public class TestBean {

private String name;
private String desc;
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getDesc() {
    return desc;
}
public void setDesc(String desc) {
    this.desc = desc;
}
}
```

code1.java

```
package test.json.MyJsonCode;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
public class Code1 extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    try {   
    response.setContentType("application/json");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");
    List<TestBean> testList = new ArrayList<TestBean>();
    TestBean test = new TestBean();
    test.setDesc("description1");
    test.setName("name1");
    testList.add(test);
    TestBean test2 = new TestBean();
    test2.setDesc("description2");
    test2.setName("name2");
    testList.add(test2);
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    System.out.println("inside code1 class");

    String jsonList = gson.toJson(testList);    
    System.out.println("json data"+jsonList);
    response.getWriter().write(jsonList);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
}
}
```

The alert is not popping up the name value.is this the right way to parse?or any corrections required in the code? Request your support and thanks in advance.

Comment: you don't need to parse the response data object, jQuery already did that

Comment: That's not entirly true @baao But if you send the correct HTPT headers and set [dataType:json](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) then you should get an object not a string

Comment: You should really set the content type using the contentType overload not the headers overload FYI

Comment: Can you include in the question the actual output (or sample by changing private data).  ie `success: function(json){ console.log(json);`  It looks like you're **returning a list**, but the jquery is **expecting a single item**.  Try: `alert(rep[0].name);`

Answer (score 0):

This is the final working code.Thanks all

```
$.ajax({  
            type: "Post",  
            url: "submit",
            data: {PartCode:varPartCode},
            ContentType:'json',
            headers: {Accept : "application/json;charset=utf-8"},
            success: function(json){
                alert(json[0].name);
             }                
          });
```